# Connection Closed error is coming while trying to connect with remote Spark master node

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have deployed a Spark cluster on a separate VM which running on a separate physical machine.I have defined the same machine as the master node. Then I tried to process spark job using remote master node.Driver application is running on my local machine. I have defined the Spark conf as follows,

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
  .setAppName("test app")
  .setMaster("spark://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:7077")
  .set("spark.deploy.mode", "cluster")
  .set("spark.driver.memory", "1g")
```

While application is running, it is given following error,

```
16/07/12 10:01:22 ERROR TransportResponseHandler: Still have 2 requests outstanding when connection from xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/xxx.xxx.xx.xxx7077 is closed
16/07/12 10:01:22 WARN AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:7077
java.io.IOException: Connection from xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:7077 closed
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler.channelUnregistered(TransportResponseHandler.java:124)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelUnregistered(TransportChannelHandler.java:94)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelUnregistered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:53)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelUnregistered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:53)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelUnregistered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:53)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelUnregistered(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:739)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$8.run(AbstractChannel.java:659)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Please be kind to help me to over come this error.

Comment: Check the spark master log

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov Thnx for your advise

Comment: It is showing following error

 ERROR OneForOneStrategy: Error while decoding incoming Akka PDU of length: 1317
akka.remote.transport.AkkaProtocolException: Error while decoding incoming Akka PDU of length: 1317
Caused by: akka.remote.transport.PduCodecException: Decoding PDU failed.

Comment: I am getting the same error in pyspark 2.0.0 in EMR .